# options within nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

Trying to make a nested form, which is working fine so far, except i need to put some dropdowns for the user to choose, as well as maybe make a couple of validations, however it seems nothing gets out of the form properly and keep getting errors no matter what I try.

three models. 
--configuration

```
  has_many :configoptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :configoptions
```

--configoption

```
  belongs_to :configuration
  has_many :items
```

and item

```
  belongs_to :configoption
  scope :sorted, order('items.position ASC')
```

Now, so far I'm creating a nested form, looping through the configoptions, but for each option is possible there's more than one item. So I want to make a drop-down for those options where this is the case.

In my view i have:

```
<p>
<th>Elements</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
</p>
<%= form_for @config, :url => {:action => 'show', :id => @config.id} do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :configoptions do |fp| %>
    <p>
        <% if :items.count > 1 %>
        <%= fp.text_field :name %>  
        <% else %>
        <% fp.select(:items, :name)%>
        <% end %>
    <%= fp.text_field :quantity %>
    </p>
  <% end %>    
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I get an error obviously telling me that it can't count the :items.

How do you think I can make this work?

Thanks!

<%= form_for @config, :url => {:action => 'show', :id => @config.id} do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :configoptions do |fp| %>

<%= fp.text_field :id %>
    <%= fp.text_field :name %>
    <%= fp.text_field :quantity %>

<% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured it out, at least it seems to be doing what I want now.

I modified the view to pass the instance of the configoption into the nested form itself to be able to create the drop downs.

```
  <% for configoption in @config.configoptions %>    
  <%= f.fields_for :configoptions, configoption do |fp| %>
    <p>
        <% if configoption.items.count > 1 %>
        <%= fp.select (:name, options_from_collection_for_select(configoption.items.sorted, 'name', 'name'))%>  
        <% else %>
```